# Android: IllegalException thrown while working with the Cursor

Tags: java, android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

I'm making an application that stores personal information in the SQLite database and show the data in the format of TableLayout in the activity. In order to implement the idea, I have created several files so far, and they are as follows.

(1) AddAPersonActivity.java: This class takes the value input, stores it into the SQLite database and adds a row with the data into a table layout that will be shown in the ViewGroupActivity.

(2) ViewGroupActivity.java: This class shows a table that stores the personal information.

(3) SQLController.java: This class defines methods for opening and closing the SQLite database, inserting data and reading the entry.

(4) SQLiteHandler.java: This class extends the SQLiteOpenHelper class and deals with creating database and table.

The codes are as follows.

(1) AddAPersonActivity.java

```
public class AddAPersonActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private Button btnAdd;
    private EditText etName;
    private TextView tvDob;
    private Spinner spNationality;
    private RadioButton rbMale, rbFemale;
    private Calendar birthday;
    private NameValidator nameValidator;
    private RadioGroup rgGenderGroup;
    private TableLayout tlViewGroup;
    private String gender = "";
    private SQLController sqlController;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Person person;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_a_person);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        tvDob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDob);
        spNationality = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spNationality);
        rbMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbMale);
        rbFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbFemale);
        rgGenderGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgGenderGroup);
        tlViewGroup = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlViewGroup);

        // Build a table
        sqlController = new SQLController(this);
        buildTable();

        // Initialise the NameValidator
        nameValidator = new NameValidator();

        birthday = Calendar.getInstance();

        // Import countries into spNationality
        Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
        ArrayList<String> countries = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Locale locale: locales) {
            String country = locale.getDisplayCountry();
            if(country.trim().length() > 0 && !countries.contains(country)) {
                countries.add(country);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(countries);
        for(String country: countries) {
            System.out.println(country);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countries);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spNationality.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spNationality.setSelection(0);

        spNationality.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        tvDob.setOnClickListener(this);
        rgGenderGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void updateLabel() {
        String format = "MM/dd/yy";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
        tvDob.setText(dateFormat.format(birthday.getTime()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAdd:

                // Create an instance of a person
                person = new Person();

                // set person's name
                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                person.setName(name);

                // set person's age
                Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
                int age = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                if(today.get(Calendar.MONTH) < birthday.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
                    age--;
                } else if(today.get(Calendar.MONTH) == birthday.get(Calendar.MONTH) && today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) < birthday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
                    age--;
                }
                person.setAge(age);

                // set person's nationality
                String nationality = spNationality.getSelectedItem().toString();
                person.setNationality(nationality);

                // set person's created time
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                java.util.Date currentDate = new java.util.Date();
                Date currentTime = new Date(currentDate.getTime());
                String created_at = dateFormat.format(currentTime);
                person.setCreated_at(created_at);

                if(!(name.length() > 0)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please don't leave the name empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if(!(tvDob.getText().toString().length() > 0)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please set a valid birthday.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if(birthday.getTime().compareTo(new java.util.Date()) > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong birthday. Please set the valid birthday again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if(!(rbMale.isChecked() || rbFemale.isChecked())) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please choose your gender.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else if(!nameValidator.validate(etName.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong name. Please enter a proper name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "New person is added to the database!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    new MyAsync().execute();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.tvDob:

                // Create a DatePickerDialog and store date info into the birthday variable.
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        birthday.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        birthday.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        birthday.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        updateLabel();
                    }
                };
                new DatePickerDialog(this, date, birthday.get(Calendar.YEAR), birthday.get(Calendar.MONTH), birthday.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    void addDataToRow(Person person) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch(checkedId) {
            case(R.id.rbMale):
                gender = "M";
                break;
            case(R.id.rbFemale):
                gender = "F";
                break;
        }
    }


    void buildTable() {
        sqlController.open();
        Cursor cursor = sqlController.readEntry();
        int rows = cursor.getCount();
        int columns = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        // Outer for loop
        for(int i=1; i<rows; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // Inner for loop
            for(int j=0; j<columns; j++) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textView.setTextSize(10);
                textView.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 5);
                textView.setText(cursor.getString(j));
                row.addView(textView);
            }

            cursor.moveToNext();
            tlViewGroup.addView(row);
        }
        sqlController.close();
    }


    private class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            tlViewGroup.removeAllViews();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
            progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            sqlController.open();
            sqlController.insertData(person);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPreExecute();
            buildTable();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

(2) ViewGroupActivity.java

```
public class ViewGroupActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TableLayout tlViewGroup;
    private TextView tvName, tvAge, tvNationality, tvGender, tvCreatedAt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewgroup);

        tlViewGroup = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlViewGroup);
        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAge);
        tvNationality = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNationality);
        tvGender = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
        tvCreatedAt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCreatedAt);

        tvName.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvAge.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvNationality.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvGender.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvCreatedAt.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.tvName:
                break;
            case R.id.tvAge:
                break;
            case R.id.tvNationality:
                break;
            case R.id.tvGender:
                break;
            case R.id.tvCreatedAt:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

(3) SQLController.java

```
public class SQLController {
    private SQLiteHandler handler;
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public SQLController(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public SQLController open() throws SQLiteException {
        handler = new SQLiteHandler(context);
        db = handler.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        handler.close();
    }

    public void insertData(Person person) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_NAME, person.getName());
        values.put(SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_AGE, person.getAge());
        values.put(SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_NATIONALITY, person.getNationality());
        values.put(SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_GENDER, person.getGender());
        values.put(SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_CREATED_AT, person.getCreated_at());
        db.insert(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }

    public Cursor readEntry() {
        String[] allColumns = new String[] {
                SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_NAME, SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_AGE, SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_NATIONALITY, SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_GENDER,
                SQLiteHandler.COLUMN_CREATED_AT
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_NAME, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

(4) SQLiteHandler.java

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // DB information
    static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    static final String DB_NAME = "sortingtester.db";

    // Table information
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "People";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_AGE = "Age";
    public static final String COLUMN_NATIONALITY = "Nationality";
    public static final String COLUMN_GENDER = "Gender";
    public static final String COLUMN_CREATED_AT = "Created_At";

    // Statement to create table
    private final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_AGE + " INT, " + COLUMN_NATIONALITY + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_GENDER + " CHAR(1) NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_CREATED_AT + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    // Statement to drop table
    private final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

When running the application and trying to start the AddAPersonActivity, I could not even reach the activity itself, as the application is forcefully closed showing the following error messages.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 5 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
            at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
            at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:439)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
            at com.marshall.dbtester.AddAPersonActivity.buildTable(AddAPersonActivity.java:221)
            at com.marshall.dbtester.AddAPersonActivity.onCreate(AddAPersonActivity.java:68)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It seems like the problem is occurring from the cursor, so I think it is also related to the layout of the ViewGroupActivity. So I'll also attach the xml file of the ViewGroupActivity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@color/default_background">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="@string/group"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/default_text"/>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.95">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlViewGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="*"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <TableRow>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvName"
                    android:text="@string/name"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAge"
                    android:text="@string/age"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvNationality"
                    android:text="@string/nationality"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvGender"
                    android:text="@string/gender"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvCreatedAt"
                    android:text="@string/created_at"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.2"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text"/>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've been struggling with this problem for quite a long time, so your advice will be very much helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the column count to the size of the cursor.

`int columns = cursor.getCount();`

User `getColumnCount()` and it probably should work.